# Matplotlib labels aren't filled correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with list of countries, years and values.

[image]

I've set an index for that data:

```
data = data.set_index(data['Country or Area'])
data.drop(['Country or Area'], axis=1, inplace=True)
data.head()
```

I'm trying to create a simple plot like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
albania = data.loc['Albania']
ax = albania[['Year','Value']].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8,5), title="Precipitation of Albania between 1990 and 2015")
ax.set_ylabel("Precipitation")
ax.set_xlabel("Years")
```

However, the bar shows y_labels with the index name 'Albania', which is not correct. It should show the range of years.

[image]

What should I do to change the labels to the correct one?

Comment: Maybe `ax = albania.set_index('Year')[['Value']].plot(kind='bar', ...)`?

Comment: The correct way: `ax = df.pivot(index='Year', columns=‘Country or Area', values='Value').plot(kind='bar', subplots=True, figsize=(8, 10))` and subplots= can be True or False

Comment: Or `ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='Year', y='Value', hue='Country or Area')`

Comment: Don’t set the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ax.set_xticklabels(albania['Year'])
```

This will set all your x-tick labels to a range of years